# Convert string representation of XML to XML DOM object in Windows 8 Javascript app

Tags: javascript, xml, dom, windows-8, windows-store-apps

I'm creating a Windows 8 JavaScript app, and I need to convert a string somewhat like this:

```
<p>
  blah blah blah
</p>
<div>
  <p>
    random dom stuff
  </p>
</div>
```

Into an XML DOM object, so I can traverse it with DOM methods (ie `getElementByID()`).

I've tried two ways

```
 //retrieve text to process
 var content = xml.querySelector("api > parse > text").textContent;

 //1
 var contentXML = new DOMParser().parseFromString(content, "text/xml");

 //2
 var newContentXML = new ActiveXObject("Microsoft.XMLDOM");
 newContentXM.async = false;
 newContentXM.loadXML(content);
```

Both fail. #1 with `Only one root element is allowed.`, and #2 with `Automation server can't create object. Can't load the ActiveX plug-in that has the class ID '{2933BF90-7B36-11D2-B20E-00C04F983E60}'. Applications can't load ActiveX controls.`

Everywhere I've looked says #2 is how you should do it in IE, and I'm presuming W8 JS apps use the same JavaScript engine as IE.

How can I convert my text to an XML DOM object?

Comment: Your first item is that you are trying to create a document form something tha isn't a valid XML document. Wrap your string fragment with a dummy root element, then DOM parser root should work.

Comment: @DominicHopton I wondered about this. Does this root element need to be an `<xml>` (or a `<html>` maybe)?

Comment: DOM Parser says it supports XML, so any root node; e.g. <FakeRoot> ** your content ** </FakeRoot>

Answer (score 2, accepted):

DOMParser is fine, and the error is accurate.  parseFromString returns *an instance* of a document, but your text doesn't define a single document root, it's a concatenation of two: a paragraph and a div.

The following will work:

```
<div>
  <p>
    blah blah blah
  </p>
  <div>
    <p>
      random dom stuff
    </p>
  </div>
</div>
```

By the way with your original string,

- Chrome's DOMParser implementation will also throw an error "Extra content at the end of the document"
- Firefox yields "XML Parsing Error: junk after document element."

Comment: Ok, well I changed it to `parseFromString("<div>"+content+"</div>", "text/xml");`, however I still got an error - `
XML5633: End-tag name does not match the corresponding start-tag name.`. Do you have any clue why this might happen? As far as I can see `div` is the same as `div`, and I'm 99.99% sure that the HTML inside `content` is correct, it renders properly in my browser. (BTW, thanks for your help. :) )

Comment: well, rendering in browser doesn't mean it's valid markup.  There's a [quick and dirty validator here](http://www.w3schools.com/xml/xml_validator.asp) - perhaps grab the `content` string via a VS debug session and check.  I tried with the simple sample above and your modification is working fine for me.

Comment: yeah, I don't have access to change the source of the webpage though, so that could be a problem. I might add the xml to the current dom, then retrieve it and process it.

Answer (score 0):

IE is a pain and does things in a much more complicated way.  While `DOMParser` works in most browsers, in IE you need to create an ActiveX object `MSXML2.DOMDocument.6.0`, `MSXML2.DOMDocument.3.0` or `MSXML2.DOMDocument` - whichever is supported first.  Here's some code that detects which to use:

```
var xml, tmp;
try {
    if (isIE)   // add your IE detection here
    {
        var versions = ["MSXML2.DOMDocument.6.0",
                "MSXML2.DOMDocument.3.0",
                "MSXML2.DOMDocument"];

        for (var i = 0; i < 3; i++){
            try {
                xml = new ActiveXObject(versions[i]);

                if (xml)
                    break;
            } catch (ex){
                xml = null;
            }
        }

        if (xml)
        {
            xml.async = "false";
            xml.loadXML(str);
        }
    }
    else {
        tmp = new DOMParser();
        xml = tmp.parseFromString(str, "text/xml");
    }
} catch(e) {
    xml = null;
}
```

Comment: Thanks for the help, I'm about to load it up. I won't need the `else { tmp = new DOMParser(); xml = tmp.parseFromString(str, "text/xml");}` surely though, as it only needs to be compatibile with the IE engine.

Comment: I'm getting the same errors I got with the original ActiveX loading: `APPHOST9603: Can't load the ActiveX plug-in that has the class ID '{88D96A05-F192-11D4-A65F-0040963251E5}'. Applications can't load ActiveX controls.
File: default.html`- one of those for each of the three DOMDOC types